# Why does the YouTube logo have "FR" in the upper left corner?

Tags: youtube

When I visit YouTube, this is what I see in the upper left corner:

[image: old YouTube logo with 'FR']

At first I thought that YouTube was thinking I'm in France, but the URL is still `https://www.youtube.com` and the rest of the site appears in English with no French anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your "Country" setting has been set to France. Look for this at the bottom of the page:

[image]

If you are in the United States you should select "Worldwide (All)"